# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Dears,
I got error when i call the ajax function.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSON (jquery?v=M6dmVkrHVhoZ1gfOtvVDZbgBcQTsbWxoLsRizcGkbPk1:1)
    at vo (jquery?v=M6dmVkrHVhoZ1gfOtvVDZbgBcQTsbWxoLsRizcGkbPk1:1)
    at k (jquery?v=M6dmVkrHVhoZ1gfOtvVDZbgBcQTsbWxoLsRizcGkbPk1:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u (jquery?v=M6dmVkrHVhoZ1gfOtvVDZbgBcQTsbWxoLsRizcGkbPk1:1)
```

This is my ajax call code:

```
   function MyFunction() {

    $.get("/Base/TestMethod", { message: 'nice' }, function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    }, 'json').fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + ": " + jqXhr.responseText);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to determine what's coming back from the HTTP request. The browser developer tools will show you that.

Comment: As @Pointy mentioned, its probably html with an error message or something but you will have to debug this yourself to see that. Most of us are not NSA so we can't see what is happening on your pc.

Comment: @Pointy, Thank you for your help :) .. Can you please tell me how can i use chrome developer tools to know what's coming from the HTTP request. sorry but i am very new in programming

Comment: Hit F12 and you should see the developer console. All XHR requests show up in the "Console" panel, and all requests of any kind show up in the "Network" panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the returned JSON was too big. Try set MaxJsonLength to max int value.

```
var jsonResult = Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return jsonResult;
```